# Consuming nuget packages in azure synapse c# notebooks from nuget feed in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, azure-synapse

We have created a dll in VS and published it to nuget feed in Azure Devops. We are able to consume it in VS since it is in the same machine with the config file. However we were unable to find a way to use it in Synapse Spark C# notebooks. We tried following commands to use it in our notebook but it gives us authentication error.
#i URL to json file
#r "nuget:Tbss.Util.Log"

Answer (score 0):

Just heard back from the product team and at this time it is not supported . They are working on this and will be supported in near future .

Answer (score 0):

This is now implemented using the magic #r syntax.

Example: `#r "Newtonsoft.Json,13.0.1"`